# initiate mongodb replica set

Tags: mongodb

I am running the following in a script to automate the initiation of a replica set:

```
var cfg = { _id: 'rs0',
    members: [
        { _id: 0, host: '192.168.1.46:27017'},
        { _id: 1, host: '192.168.1.51:27017'},
        { _id: 2, host: '192.168.1.48:27017'}
    ]
};

var error = rs.initiate(cfg);
printjson(error);
```

However I am getting :

```
{ "ok" : 0, "errmsg" : "Missing expected field \"version\"", "code" : 93 }
```

After I run the script and am not sure why.

I have tried running the script locally as well using the following:

```
mongo 192.168.1.46:27017 /opt/scripts/initreplset.js
```

I am using mongodb v3.2.

Comment: Since you are really just invoking a `mongo` shell instance, then any programming wrapping this is really irrelevant. You are basically asking how to configure a replica set. That is a question for [dba.stackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange,com) instead. Though the error should be self explanatory.

Answer (score 7):

I'm having the same problem now, probably is something quite new,
anyway it seems that the version field is now mandatory.

From the official documentation:

> version
>   Type: int
>
> An incrementing number used to distinguish revisions of the replica
>   set configuration object from previous iterations of the
>   configuration.

So probably you just need to add this number. 
I.e.:

```
{
   "_id" : "rs0",
   "version" : 1,
   "members" : [
      {
         "_id" : 1,
         "host" : "mongodb0.example.net:27017"
      }
   ]
}
```